# Run osascript (AppleScript) from launchd / launctl

Tags: macos, applescript, launchd, macos-mojave

I am trying to run a very simple AppleScript periodically using a `launchd` agent but it won't do anything aside from writing the AppleScript contents to `stdout`.

My `launchd` Agent at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.nn.test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.nn.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
      <string>-e</string>
      <string>"display dialog \"Hi\""</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>7200</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/testout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am running by:

```
$ launchctl unload com.nn.test.plist
$ launchctl load com.nn.test.plist
$ launchctl run com.nn.test
```

Result is `cat /tmp/testout`

```
display dialog "Hi"
```

While `/tmp/test` is empty.

**Expected behaviour** would be that a dialog opens just like when I run the command directly in the shell (which works) but it seems nothing is happening. **What am I doing wrong and why do I not see any error messages in any error log?**

Might this have to do with Mojave's enhanced security model? Can't AppleScript be run from `launchd` agents any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doubly-stringified!

You need:

```
    <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>-e</string>
    <string>display dialog "Hi"</string>
    </array>
```

and:

```
launchctl start com.nn.test
```

Comment: badum... tzzz. Thanks!